# Use search icon with react-select v2

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Anyone have any idea how to use a custom icon with react-select v2? Version 1 used to have an `arrowRenderer` prop that you could pass in with a function that would render something different. That doesn't seem to be working on v2.

Here's what I have currently:

```
renderSearchIcon = () => (
  <svg {...svgProps}>
    <path d={path} />
  </svg> 
)

<Select
  {...this.props}
  arrowRenderer={this.renderSearchIcon}
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
  options={options}
  onChange={onSelectChange}
/>
```

But for some reason I'm still getting the default down chevron. Anyone know if it's possible to do this on v2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/685#issuecomment-420213835

https://react-select.com/components

Sample snippet:

```
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';

const DropdownIndicator = props => {
  return (
    components.DropdownIndicator && (
      <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={props.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? "caret-up" : "caret-down"}/>
      </components.DropdownIndicator>
    )
  );
};


<Select
  components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
  // pass other props
/>
```